# Нужно изменить структуру кода

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, node-modules, multer

Работаю с multer'ом. У меня совсем не получается принять POST запрос так, чтобы он сохранил файл, а название дозаписал в файлик.
В postman'e всё отправляется как надо и дозаписывается тоже грамотно, а при работе с формой

```html
<form ref='uploadForm' 
      id='uploadForm' 
      action='http://kulonful.ru:8000/upload' 
      method='post' 
      encType="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name='file' />
        <input type="text" name="title" />
        <input type='submit' value='Upload' />
    </form>
```

файл записывается как нужно, а название не может записаться (undefined). Проблема в том, что запись переменных storage и upload происходит раньше, чем запрос пользователя.. Помогите изменить структуру кода.

```js
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '../../../../../../var/www/sources/audio/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var all_audio_cut = all_audio.slice(0,-1), ids = 0;
        for(var a = 0; a<all_audio_cut.length; a++)
        {
            if(all_audio_cut[a] == '{') {ids = ids+1;}
        }
        all_audio_cut = all_audio_cut + ',{"id":"' + ids + '","title":"' + req.body.title + '"}]';
        var filenames = "mus" + ids + ".mp3";
        all_audio = all_audio_cut;
        fs.writeFile("audio.cfg", all_audio_cut);
        cb(null, filenames);
    },
    onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
    }
})

var upload = multer({storage:storage})

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
    res.send('Аудиозапись была загружена на сервер');
})
```